# Flow using "Send Slack Message" element and a view

Tags: tooling-api, modal, view, slack

I want to send a Slack message from a flow using a view, and there is a beta release for this that I want to try out in a sandbox. The flow does send a plain text Slack message without a view. So this is what I have done so far.

1. Created a .view file using Visual Code and got it deployed
2. Created an apex class for it (I wish to have a submit button)
3. Created a small test flow, which works fine without all the beta features

Now the flow element asks for the .view file, so I enter the name I gave it. "test.view", but this fails when I debug. It asks for the API name of the .view file. I have tried different variations of the name of the view, but nothing is accepted, and the documentation does not mention anything about the API name. I guess the docs are more for when one creates a Slack app from scratch. The docs for the flow element do not say anything useful either.

To my knowledge, this type of metadata does not have an API name. Does anyone of you have a clue?